# country name not show on geochart

Tags: javascript, java, google-visualization

This is my code

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() 
 { 
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTfxVvfDKn6iXn4W_m7HJ_86JOGNDsxYSSaXipEo0vM/edit#gid=0');
      // query.setQuery('select A,B,C');
        query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
        }
function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +    response.getDetailedMessage());
       return;
     }

 var options = {
  
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
 colorAxis:  {colors: ['#D95F0E','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FFF7BC','#FFF7BC','#FFF7BC','#FFF7BC',]}, 
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 }, 
 datalessRegionColor: '#F5F0E7',
 displayMode: 'regions', 
 enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
 resolution: 'countries',
 sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
 region:'world',
 keepAspectRatio: true,
 width:800,
 height:600,
 tooltip: {isHtml:'true',textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus'} 
 };
  var data = response.getDataTable();
 var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,{
   type:'string',
   label : 'num of',
   calc: function (dt, row) {
           return {
            v: dt.getValue(row, 1),
            f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + ':  (' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + ' .)'
        }
    }
}]);
   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
 chart.draw(view, options);
 }
 </script>
 <div id='visualization'></div>
```

and the spreadsheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTfxVvfDKn6iXn4W_m7HJ_86JOGNDsxYSSaXipEo0vM/edit#gid=0

I don't know why the country name in the first column not show on the geochart
and how can I customize the tooltips such as.. add line break instead of colon(:) I tried br / but it didn't work

anyone can help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added the following properties to the calculated view field...

```
role: 'tooltip',
p: {html: true}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['geochart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTfxVvfDKn6iXn4W_m7HJ_86JOGNDsxYSSaXipEo0vM/edit#gid=0');
  query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
}

function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    console.log('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +      response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
    colorAxis:  {colors: ['#D95F0E','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FEC44F','#FFF7BC','#FFF7BC','#FFF7BC','#FFF7BC',]},
    backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:0 },
    datalessRegionColor: '#F5F0E7',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
    resolution: 'countries',
    sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
    region:'world',
    keepAspectRatio: true,
    width:800,
    height:600,
    tooltip: {isHtml:'true',textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus'}
  };

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, {
    type:'string',
    label : 'num of',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + ':  (' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + ' .)'
    },
    role: 'tooltip',
    p: {html: true}
  }]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='visualization'></div>
```