# GeoChart: formatting the tooltip

Tags: google-visualization

I'm drawing a GeoChart taking the data directly from a Google Sheet. The spreadsheet has this structure:

```
ISO 3166-2  NumValue1   NumValue2   Country name
XX          XX          XX          XX
XX          XX          XX          XX
```

I want to use `Col0` as regions identifier and Col1 as the value, and I want to display `Col3` as tooltip title, and `Col1` & `Col2` in the tooltip (with the col header as label).

The code below works (regions are displayed using `Col0` and the value is taken from `Col1`), but I need to change it so that the tooltip shows data from the other columns (and not from `Col0`).

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
      var query = new google['visualization'].Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/____&headers=1&range=A1:C')
      query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
  }

  function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
      }

      var options = {
          displayMode: 'regions',
          sizeAxis: {
              minValue: 0,
              maxValue: 5
          },
          colorAxis: {
              colors: ['#fff', '#000']
          },
          legend: 'none'
      };

      var data = response.getDataTable();

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
      table.draw(data, {
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%'
      });
  };
```

I have read the documentation and it seems that be best way is to change `chart.draw(data, options);` to `chart.draw(view, options);`, adding this before that:

```
// defines the data for the tooltip
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('{0}');
formatter.format( data, [0,1], 1 );
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('{2}');
formatter.format( data, [0,1,2], 0 );

// defines the data for the chart values
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1]);
```

But I really don't understand how to use the formatter to show the tooltip as:

```
Col3 (Title)
Col1 (label): Col1 value
Col2 (label): Col2 value
```

Also, whenever I change the query URL to include the forth column (`&range=A1:D`) I get the `Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 3 columns)` error.

Comment: formatter can't be used to add custom tooltip, need extra column with `role: 'tooltip'` -- check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42892829/5090771) for adding to query result using a data view ...

Comment: @WhiteHat thanks! it works